# Why is b' ' included in the excel file after web scraping?

Tags: web-scraping

I'm learning web scraping and was able to scrape data from a website to an excel file. However, in the excel file, you can see that it also includes b' ', instead of just the strings (names of Youtube channels, uploads, views). Any idea where this came from?[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'} # Need to use this otherwise it returns error 403. 
url = requests.get('https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/50/mostviewed', headers=headers)
#print(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find('div', attrs = {'style': 'float: right; width: 900px;'}).find_all('div', recursive = False)[4:] # If in the inspect of the website, it uses class, then instead of 'style", type in '_class = ' instead. We don't need the first 4 rows, so [4:]

file = open('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/My_Projects/Web_scraping/topyoutubers.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file)

# write header rows

writer.writerow(['Username', 'Uploads', 'Views'])


for row in rows:
    username = row.find('a').text.strip()
    numbers = row.find_all('span', attrs = {'style': 'color:#555;'})
    uploads = numbers[0].text.strip()
    views = numbers[1].text.strip()

    print(username + ' ' + uploads + ' ' + views)
    writer.writerow([username.encode('utf-8'), uploads.encode('utf-8'), views.encode('utf-8')])

file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by the way you do your `encoding` - you might better define it once while opening the file:

```
file = open('topyoutubers.csv', 'w',  encoding='utf-8')
```

**New code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'} # Need to use this otherwise it returns error 403. 
url = requests.get('https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/50/mostviewed', headers=headers)
#print(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find('div', attrs = {'style': 'float: right; width: 900px;'}).find_all('div', recursive = False)[4:] # If in the inspect of the website, it uses class, then instead of 'style", type in '_class = ' instead. We don't need the first 4 rows, so [4:]

file = open('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/My_Projects/Web_scraping/topyoutubers.csv', 'w',  encoding='utf-8')
writer = csv.writer(file)

# write header rows

writer.writerow(['Username', 'Uploads', 'Views'])


for row in rows:
    username = row.find('a').text.strip()
    numbers = row.find_all('span', attrs = {'style': 'color:#555;'})
    uploads = numbers[0].text.strip()
    views = numbers[1].text.strip()

    print(username + ' ' + uploads + ' ' + views)
    writer.writerow([username, uploads, views])

file.close()
```

**Output**

```
    Username                    Uploads     Views
1   T-Series                    15,029      143,032,749,708
2   Cocomelon - Nursery Rhymes  605         93,057,513,422
3   SET India                   48,505      78,282,384,002
4   Zee TV                      97,302      59,037,594,757
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. Do you know why it works the way it is? I was following a Youtube tutorial and it worked for them even when they used writer.writerow([username.encode('utf-8'), uploads.encode('utf-8'), views.encode('utf-8')])

Comment: Do not know the tutorial, so there are a lot of things, that can cause that, ... but any way, it might be more clear if you define the encoding with opening the file and do not encode each variable separat, while the file has a possible different encoding.